# Is there any short form of "am not"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, inversion, contractions

We use short forms for verb + *not* like *isn't, aren't, hasn't, won't, wasn't* etc. But I haven't seen any short form used for ***am+not***. So, I want to know if any short form exists for *am not*.

<sup>Note: In one book I had seen that *aren't* can be used for *am+not*. Is this right?</sup>

Comment: *Aren't* for *am not* has its own special rule: it's only possible with inversion.  *Aren't I* is perfectly grammatical, but *\*I aren't* is ungrammatical.

Comment: "Amn't" is used only Scotland.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using very informal language you can use ain't.

> I ain't happy about this.

But even native speakers wouldn't necessarily say that, as it's a colloquialism that not everyone uses.  I would say:

> I'm not happy about this.

Comment: To add, I've seen the form "aren't" following a statement, like "*I am trying to be useful today, **aren't** I?*"

Comment: "Ain't" is grammatical, but it carries more cultural associations than most contractions: it can suggest the speaker is uneducated, rural, or low-class (or a combination of those). People sometimes avoid it for this reason alone, and either avoid a contraction entirely, or use a not-quite-correct substitution like "aren't" (as Victor Bazarov notes). If a novelist writes dialog with the word "ain't" they are almost certainly trying to convey something about the speaker's demeanor or background. I have seen the contraction "amn't" used instead of "ain't" but I don't think it is widely accepted.